# Select first en Join Eloquent Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

espero me puedan ayudar con este query en un Join de Eloquent.

Tengo la tabla **Productos**

| Campo | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 1 |
| Nombre | Sala |
| SKU | Sala001 |

Tengo la tabla **Historicos**

| Campo | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 1 |
| producto_id | 1 |
| costo | 1234 |
| fecha | fecha |

Necesito un query en Eloquent de Laravel para obetener todos los productos pero solo regresarme con un Join, el primer historico del producto.
Ya que puede haber muchos hitoricos por el cambio de costos, necesito el más reciente a la fecha actual.

Tenía este query, que en su momento me funcionaba, pero de un día a otro me dio un error de syntaxis en mysql.

```
$productos = DB::table('productos')
        ->join('historicos', function ($join) use ($date)  {
            $join->on('productos.id', '=', 'historicos.producto_id')
                 ->where('historicos.fecha', '<=', $date)
                 ->orderByDesc('historicos.fecha')
                 ->first();
                })
        ->get();
    
        return $productos;
```

Si dejo el first(), me da error, no funciona con un take(1) o un limit(1), no me da error, pero me sigue devolviendo todos los históricos de cada producto, solo necesito el primero, como con un first, pero me da error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el primer registro de la tabla historicos para cada producto, puedes utilizar el método latest de Eloquent, que te permite ordenar los resultados de una consulta por un campo en particular y retornar el primer resultado.

En tu caso, el código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$productos = DB::table('productos')
        ->join('historicos', function ($join) use ($date)  {
            $join->on('productos.id', '=', 'historicos.producto_id')
                 ->where('historicos.fecha', '<=', $date);
                })
        ->latest('historicos.fecha')
        ->get();
    
return $productos;
```

En la consulta, primero realizamos el join entre las tablas productos y historicos, filtrando solo aquellos registros de la tabla historicos cuyo campo fecha sea menor o igual a la fecha actual. Luego, utilizamos el método latest para ordenar los resultados por el campo fecha de manera descendente y retornar el primer registro de la tabla historicos para cada producto.

Finalmente, utilizamos el método get para ejecutar la consulta y retornar los resultados.

Comment: Usar chatGPT está prohibido en [es.so], además, usar chatGPT sin citar la fuente es considerado [Plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio). Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes), [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por este motivo.

Comment: Seguí tu recomendación, pero sigue regresando todos los valores de Históricos, tengo 2 históricos por producto, como ejemplo. Pero sigue regresando los dos valores de cada uno y no el primero igual o menor que la fecha actual.

Answer (score 0):

Seguí investigando y encontré esta solución, me sirvió, espero a alguien más le funcione.

Seguí la documentación de Laravel e hice uso de **Subquery Joins**, les dejo la [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-joins).

Primero se hace una consulta sobre los **historicos** y agrupo por producto_id, después añado ese query al query principal de **productos**.

Al final mi query quedó así:

```
    $historicos = DB::table('historicos')
                ->select('producto_id', DB::raw('MAX(precioSI) as precio'))
                ->where('fecha', '<=', $date)
               ->groupBy('producto_id');

    $productos = DB::table('productos')
    ->joinSub($historicos, 'historico', function ($join) {
        $join->on('productos.id', '=', 'historico.producto_id');
    })->get();

    return $productos;
```

Y listo me regresa el primer historico de cada producto, con fecha <= que la fecha establecida.